# Apache Solr Index Bechmarking

Tags: solr

I recently started playing around with Apache Solr and currently trying to figure out the best way to benchmark the indexing of a corpus of XML documents. I am basically interested in the throughput (documents indexed/second) and index size on disk.

I am doing all this on Ubuntu.

Benchmarking Technique

* Run the following 5 times& get average total time taken ***

- Index documents [`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core/dataimport?command=full-import`]

  - Get 'Time taken' name attribute from XML response when status is 'idle' [curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core/dataimport]
  - Get size of 'data/index' directory
- Delete Index [`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'`]
- Commit [`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/w5/update --data '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'`]
- Re-index documents

Questions

1. I intend to calculate my throughput by dividing the number of documents indexed by average total time taken; is this fine?
2. Are there tools (like SolrMeter for query benchmarking) or standard scripts already available that I could use to achive my objectives? I do not want to re-invent the wheel...
3. Is my approach fine?
4. Is there an easier way of getting the index size as opposed to performing a 'du' on the data/index/ directory?
5. Where can I find information on how to interpret XML response attributes (see sample output below). For instance, I would want to know the difference between the `QTime` and `Time taken` values.

* XML Response Used to Get Throughput ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">w5-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <str name="status">idle</str>
  <str name="importResponse"/>
  <lst name="statusMessages">
    <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
    <str name="Total Rows Fetched">3200</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
    <str name="Full Dump Started">2012-12-11 14:06:19</str>
    <str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1600 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Processed">1600</str>
    <str name="Time taken">0:0:10.233</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To question 1:

I would suggest you should try to index more than 1 XML (with different dataset) file and compare the given results. Thats the way you will know if it´s ok to simply divide the taken time with your number of documents.

To question 2:

I didn´t find any of these tools, I did it by my own by developing a short Java application

To question 3:

Which approach you mean? I would link to my answer to question 1...

To question 4:

The size of the index folder gives you the correct size of the whole index, why don´t you want to use it?

To question 5:

The results you get in the posted XML is transfered through a XSL file. You can find it in the /bin/solr/conf/xslt folder. You can look up what the termes exactly means AND you can write your own XSL to display the results and informations.
Note: If you create a new XSL file, you have to change the settings in your solrconfig.xml. If you don´t want to make any changes, edit the existing file.

edit: I think the difference is, that the Qtime is the rounded value of the taken time value. There are only even numbers in Qtime.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you for this. The plan is to index different sized datasets and I've already set up 15 cores to work with. In question 3, I was trying to find out if my logic is not flawed.

Comment: Please tell us what you find out, I´m quite interested in that too :-) I can tell you, that I needed 6minutes to index 660.000 documents. I think this depends on the RAM you give to solr. You can change the value in the solrconfig.xml.

Comment: I don´t think your logic is flawed, but you have to interpret your results correctly. Your benchmark results depend on your system environment - in other systems the values can hardly differ.

Comment: Working with a Pentium Dual-Core E5200@ 2.50GHz with 4GM RAM, I managed a maximum throughput (docs/sec) of 803 for a workload of 25,600 xml documents. My largest workload --composed of 1.6million xml documents-- took ~5hours, with a throughput of 90 docs/sec. Incidentally, the xml documents have a total of 15 unique fields, however, the structure is not fixed and all fields are repeatable.